# Defining LINQ query to convert db table to new pivot table in ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api

I've created a pivot table through a stored procedure in SQL Server. But the problem is when I've added the SP to my Entity Data Model in Entity Framework then it gives me the return type "INT" as you can see in the following code:

TestContext.cs:

```
   public virtual int getMonthIsin(Nullable<System.DateTime> fromDate, Nullable<System.DateTime> toDate)
            {
                var fromDateParameter = fromDate.HasValue ?
                    new ObjectParameter("fromDate", fromDate) :
                    new ObjectParameter("fromDate", typeof(System.DateTime));

                var toDateParameter = toDate.HasValue ?
                    new ObjectParameter("toDate", toDate) :
                    new ObjectParameter("toDate", typeof(System.DateTime));

                return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("getMonthIsin", fromDateParameter, toDateParameter);
            }
```

When I click on the SP in function imports (EDM) and call the column information then it gets me the correct pivot table with the correct columns. But I don't know how to return it with the WebApi.

Well, my idea was it, to define the pivot table as LINQ query.

Here is the SQL code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getMonthIsin]
    @fromDate datetime,
    @toDate datetime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @colIsin nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)

    SET FMTONLY OFF;

    WITH vals AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT ds.QR_Fond_isin AS isin
        FROM QR_DS021s ds
    )

    SELECT @colIsin = COALESCE(@colIsin + ', ', '') + '['+ isin +']'
    FROM vals
    ORDER BY isin

    SET @query = 'SELECT *
                    FROM (SELECT ROUND(ds.ct_quot_rate,0) AS Erfuellungsgrad,
                                 ROUND(ds.ct_quot_rate,0) AS Quote,
                                 ds.QR_Fond_isin AS isin
                          FROM QR_DS021s ds INNER JOIN QR_Fonds f ON ds.QR_Fond_isin = f.isin
                          WHERE ds.datum >= @from_val AND ds.datum <= @to_val
                          ) t
                          PIVOT (
                            COUNT(Quote)
                            FOR isin IN ('+ @colIsin +')
                          ) p
                          ORDER BY Erfuellungsgrad DESC'

    EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@from_val datetime, @to_val datetime', @from_val = @fromDate, @to_val = @toDate
```

Do anyone has an idea to define the SQL query to LINQ query in my webapi? Or how to define the Stored Procedure in WebAPI if it's possible?!

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Do you have any idea.. I've read a comment in an other thread that you have skills about that.

Comment: Is the result shape always the same?

Comment: @GertArnold You mean the column shape? The isin is dynamic because when the user added a new isin then the pivot table have to add a new column with this new isin.